# Checking encryption status of email.

Tags: python, perl, email, encryption, pgp

I've been working with gpg-mailgate recently and have it working almost how I want it.

My last little hurdle is how do **reliably** check to see if an incoming email is already pgp encrypted.  Here are the options I see.

1. Add a content filter in postfix that uses Mail::gpg.is_encrypted and if the message returns yes then send directly on.  If not then I can send it to gpg-mailgate to deal with it.
2. Call a small perl script from within gpg-mailgate and once again call Mail::GPG.is_encrypted and go from there.  I saw a few examples of calling perl from within python and I'd prefer to do it this way.
3. I can **unreliably** test for encryption by looking for *****BEGIN PGP MESSAGE***** but that is in no way a great solution.

That's all I came up with.  Since there is nothing in the gnupg python wrapper to test for this I think I'm going to have to look at calling something else.

What I'm worried about in the first 2 scenarios is performance.  I'm trying to stay from as much unnecessary load as possible.

I'm open to all suggestions, thanks.

Comment: this would be a cool project for a neural network.  maybe try ann with some kind of feedback where you show it a bunch of emails of each type (to train it) then have it try and guess unknown ones and give it feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A GPG or other OpenPGP message sent by email should be sent in [RFC 2015](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2015.txt) format. Which is very simple to detect, reliably and efficiently.

Basically, you're just checking that the RFC822 headers have a `Content-Type` that looks like this:

```
Content-Type: multipart/encrypted; boundary=whatever; protocol="application/pgp-encrypted"
```

The ideal way to do this is with the `email` and `mime` modules in Python, or your favorite equivalents from CPAN in perl, but you can probably do it faster with a well-crafted regexp. (If you choose to go this way, look for a pre-tested regexps for RFC822 headers and build on that, because you will get parts of RFC822 wrong the first 20 times you do it. Continuation lines, optional whitespace all over the place, variable order of components, case insensitivity, etc.)

---

But what if someone just sent a raw OpenPGP message as the text of an email? At least some MUAs will detect that and treat it the same as a proper OpenPGP message. How do they do that? Basically, the way you suggested: by scanning the body.

The first part of that is to get the body itself. If they're just using a plain-text mailer, or a fancy mailer that's not stupid, it'll just be the body of a non-multipart RFC 822 message, which is easy. But if you want to handle mailers that like to HTMLify everything, you'll need to find the text/plain part, before you can even scan. Doing that reliably or quickly isn't too bad, but both?

Now, how do you tell if a message body is OpenPGP? [RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880) describes the format. In particular, look at section 6.2 about the ASCII armor format.

But briefly: Look for an armor header line, `-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----`, then zero or more RFC-822 headers, then a blank line, then a block of data that's all base-64 characters and whitespace, then the armor tail line `-----END PGP MESSAGE-----`. You may want to allow arbitrary lines before and after the header and tail for safety (it doesn't make the scan any harder). Anything that matches that is very, very likely to be an OpenPGP message; anything that doesn't is unlikely to be usable with GPG.

---

This still won't handle every possible case that people might use. If someone sends an OpenPGP multi-part message split across two emails, drags and drops an OpenPGP message in a way that makes their mailer turn it into an attachment instead of the body, pastes a binary OpenPGP message instead of an ASCII-armored one, …

But I suspect handling just proper OpenPGP MIME, and raw OpenPGP ASCII armor in the plaintext body, should be enough.

Comment: Thanks much.  I think I like the regexp path most, even though me and regexp have never been great friends.  I hadn't thought about going that route but I guess when you get right down to it that's probably what any wrapper you find will do.

Comment: I quickly threw in a few logging lines to dump the raw message.      User-Agent: K-9 Mail for Android
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Subject: Test logging  So content-type is not going to be as helpful as I had hoped.

Comment: @TheEditor: Most wrappers will _not_ use a regexp; they'll use full RFC2822 and MIME parsers. Code written that way will be a lot simpler, and more robust. The only reason to hack up a regexp instead is if the full parser turns out to be too slow—which seems plausible in you use case, but you really should try it first and see, instead of just assuming it.

Comment: @TheEditor: For your second comment, I know some MUAs do ignore OpenPGP's recommendations to use MIME, and I also know that many people use MUAs that don't do OpenPGP at all, and work around it by pasting ASCII-armored messages into plain-text messages (or by using a plugin or helper that does that for them). So you really need both OpenPGP MIME, and raw OpenPGP ASCII armor in the plaintext bodies. (You may need more, but I don't think you will. So start with the two common cases and get that working, and that may be all you ever need.)

Comment: Thanks again.  I'm learning as I go here so I appreciate all the info.

Comment: @TheEditor: Really, at this point, you're reverse-engineering what dozens or more different programs, hacked-together scripts, and individual users are doing. Unless you're trying to sell a commercial product or service—and maybe even if you are—I'd just start by implementing the standard stuff, and any non-standard stuff you've actually seen, and add more when you or your users notice a problem…